# Способы применения директив #region и #endregion в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Я вот прочитал про `#region` и `#endregion` что они нужны для группировки членов классов, но более подробно не нашел. Хочу понять более подробно.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region

Comment: Полезность директив `#region` и `#endregion` довольно сомнительна. Я бы посоветовал вообще избегать их использования.

Comment: Согласен с @FoggyFinder, бездумное использование может навредить - можно разместить `#region` в одном методе, а `#endregion` - в другом и студия благополучно позволит свернуть блок, что введет читателя в заблуждение

Comment: Не тянет на полноценный ответ, но: на моем проекте 10 лет назад приняли code style, который предполагал активное использование #region. 5 лет назад поняли, что это было ошибкой - ничего, кроме сомнительного "удовольствия" "не видеть код" эта директива не дает. Не используйте ее.

Comment: Чтобы не пропустить свёрнутый код, в Visual Studio можно отключить автоматическое сворачивание регионов: Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced->Outlining "Collapse #regions on file open".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Директива `#region` позволяет указать блок кода, который можно
>   разворачивать и сворачивать с помощью функции структурирования в
>   редакторе кода `Visual Studio`. В больших файлах кода очень удобно
>   сворачивать или скрывать одну или несколько областей, чтобы не
>   отвлекать внимание от той части файла, над которой в настоящее время
>   идет работа.

Пример

```
#region MyClass definition  
public class MyClass   
{  
    static void Main()   
    {  
    }  
}  
#endregion
```

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region)

Comment: т.е. несколько классов можно туда засунуть.

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев Да, можно и несколько классов засунуть в эту директиву. Также можно засунуть просто некоторые участки, которые в данный момент не представляют интерес.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо большое

Comment: Прятать в регион один класс или метод - глупое занятие, их и без того свернуть можно.

Comment: Лучше показать на стандартном для VS младше 2015 примере: автоматическая реализация интерфейса в студии.

Comment: *которые в данный момент не представляют интерес* - кажется это лишнее

Answer (score 16):

Представьте, что у вас есть класс, который наследует несколько интерфейсов.

Вы реализуете все необходимые методы, при этом группируете их при помощи регионов.

Вот это, пожалуй, самый типовой кейс, который подразумевается, когда говорят о группировке при помощи регионов.

Второй типовой пример -- сокрытие в регионах вложенных классов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class MyClass : IFoo, IBar
{
    # region [ IFoo implementation ]
    public void Foo1()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Foo2()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Foo3()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion

    #region [ IBar implementation]
    public int Bar1()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Bar2()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}

public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo1();
    void Foo2();
    void Foo3();
}


public interface IBar
{
    int Bar1();
    string Bar2();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Я часто использую `#region`, чтобы спрятать большие куски boilerplate-кода. Хороший пример — реализация dependency property в WPF. Такое множество кода:

```
#region dependency property FieldValue Value
public FieldValue Value
{
    get { return (FieldValue)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(FieldValue), typeof(SingleField));
#endregion
```

на самом деле совершенно избыточно, поэтому имеет смысл свернуть его, чтобы не тратить на него время, и видеть лишь

```
[dependency property FieldValue Value]
```

Comment: Понятно. Меня недавно взяли на стажировку и дали мне старый проект, чтоб я посмотрел код и исправил баги. scottishmotors.com сайт который сделано на asp.net mvc 5

Comment: Поэтому я спросил

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев: Вот и хорошо, надеюсь, что помогло!